# How do I add multiple items using google wallet digital goods?

Tags: php, android-pay

I am trying to add multiple items using google digital goods, what I want is for my users to be able to checkout with multiple items that are in their cart. Here is the code(not full code) with one item. How can I add multiple?

```
$payload = array(
    "iss" => $row['seller_identifier'], "aud" => "Google",
    "typ" => "google/payments/inapp/item/v1", "exp" => time() + 3600,
    "iat" => time(),
     "request" => array(
        "name"       => $_SESSION["itemname"],
        "price"      => $_SESSION["itemprice"], "currencyCode" => "USD",
        "sellerData" => "user_id:" . $this->userid
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple digital content items are not supported by design in the [Google Wallet for digital goods API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/).

Depending on your use case, you can either sell the items individually (e.g. something like a "Buy Now" button) or calculate the total cost and place one bundle transaction.