# Google wallet API Integration questions

Tags: android-pay, jwt

I am new to integrate Google Wallet and there are some confusion and questions related to that given below:

1. Is it possible to add multiple items for Google wallet?
2. How to handle discount by API?
3. What's the parameter in JWT response on postback URL for success and failure transaction?
4. Is refund functionality available for a transaction by API call?

Anyone have idea about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify which specific API ([Instant Buy](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/) or [Wallet for Digital](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/))?

> Is it possible to add multiple items...

- Digital - no, you can however "bundle", see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18500719/304683) for clarification.
- Instant Buy - it's just a "layer" on top of your (pre) existing purchase/ordering processes and handles (just) the payment data of a Google Wallet user. The "order details" is something you control. [See sample of data you send](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/tutorial#create_a_full_wallet_request_jwt).

> Discounts by API

*By API* - no. You can pass whatever (pre-calculated) value in both APIs.

> Success vs. Failure Postback

- Digital - Google will only send HTTP Post to your server URL on successful transaction. [See #5](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#5): *"Google sends an HTTP POST message to the postback URL whenever a purchase completes..."*
- Instant Buy - not relevant. *You are processing the transaction*, unlike in Digital where *Google is*. Instant Buy in a nutshell provides your web site, secure access to a Google Wallet user's data. You need to have your own merchant account/processor, be PCI compliant, etc. That said, you will have the success or failure info that [you actually have to send to Google](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/tutorial#notify_api_name_of_the_transaction_status) - they need to know if you have successfully processed or not (yup, it's the other way around).

> Refund by API

By API - Unless a Googler says otherwise, AFAIK, not at this time, for both APIs.

On that note, for Instant Buy, it's actually unclear to me how to "inform Google" when performing a credit or refund. Its still a "private API" (not GA) so I actually haven't seen its "guts". It's understood that since the merchant uses their own processor that a credit/refund is the same procedure, but letting Google "know" about it (days/weeks after the fact) is something I personally have no actual info on..sorry...I can assume some "button" in merchant center for Instant Buy, but that's just a guess....

Hth....

Comment: Thank you so much.... I am using wallet for digital API on http://pcgamesupply.com

Answer (score 0):

W.r.t InstantBuy Refunds:

The Refund happens on the virtual one time card that is returned by the Google API. The refund on the card can be done by using any backend payment processor. Once the refund is made to the card, it hits the user's backing card.

Comment: Thank you - Am assuming this is based on actual practice? Can you further clarify that this "informs Google" of the refund - in other words, yes, it's understood that refunding is easily accomplished. Clarification is needed on how Google will "know" about this - re: the card holder will because his/her card will be refunded, what about the Wallet interface - will it reflect it as well (automatically - since there seems to be no "call" to "update" the transaction regarding the refund)?